# is there a way to check if some code in Magento 2 is performed by a web API call

Tags: magento2, rest-api, stock

I am update a product stock item using the Magento API: `<magento_url>/rest/V1/products/<sku>/stockItems/<item_id>`

and I have now setup a plugin to override the default Magento behaviour. However, I'd like this behaviour to only be changed when the API code is called.

In other words, if I change the stock from the backend, I'd like my plugin to be ignored. thanks for your comments

Answer (score 2):

I have now found the solution. The below will only trigger my plugin in web api area.

```
<?php
        
    use Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\Data\StockItemInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\App\Area;
    
    class ForceInStockFlag
    {
        /**
         * @var \Magento\Framework\App\State
         */
        private $state;
        /**
         * @var \Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Indexer\Stock\Action\Rows
         */
        private $rowStockAction;
    
        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\App\State $state          
        ) {
            $this->state = $state;
        }
    
        public function aroundVerifyStock(
            \Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\StockStateProvider $subject,
            callable $proceed,
            StockItemInterface $stockItem
        ) {
            $result = $proceed($stockItem);
    
            if ($this->state->getAreaCode() === Area::AREA_WEBAPI_REST && $result) {
                /// trigger custom code only relevant for web api call
            }
    
            return $result;
        }
    }
```